# Django template is adding its name to path of image, preventing image from being found

Tags: django

I am working with images uploaded using ImageFields and `upload_to`path and name, and these images end up in the correct directory `media/img/whatevs/`. In my settings.py I have the following two lines.

`MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')`

`MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`

Now, in the template that matches my / URL, these images display properly and I can see/inspect that the path ends up pointing correctly to `media/img/whatevs/imgname.jpg`

However, when I want to display these images in another template called `product.html` that does not match the / url, then the path ends up pointing to `product/media/img/whatevs/imgname.jpg` instead of to `media/img/whatevs/imgname.jpg`, resulting in a 404. Somehow the name of the template is added to the img src path automatically. If I inspect it I see that the text points to `media/img/whatevs/imgname.jpg` but then if I hover my mouse over it I end up seeing this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/media/img/whatevs/imgname.jpg`.

For clarity I add what I have in my files:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('product/<slug>', ItemDetailView.as_view(), name='product'),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_upload_path)
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

product.html, where it does not display

```
<img src='media/img/whatevs/{{ item.slug }}' class="img-fluid" alt="">
```

home.html, where it displays properly

```
 <img src='media/img/whatevs/{{ item.slug }}' class="card-img-top" alt="">
```

I am working with Django 3.0.6 in debug mode.

Any clue what I am doing wrong and why the template name is added to the path and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it works on homepage and not in the other pages is because HTML anchors paths are relative since they are missing a slash(/) at the beginning. But still it is best practice to you link Item.image this way:

```
<img src='{{ item.image.url }}' class="img-fluid" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

if you uploaded images and you configured settings `settings.py` well and also your `urls.py` do there is no need of force you html to found the images like this

```
<img src='media/img/whatevs/{{ item.slug }}' class="img-fluid" alt="">
```

you have to do it like this

```
<img src='{{ item.slug.url }}' class="img-fluid" alt="">
```

this will work better

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you use relative paths in the template, instead of this:

```
<img src='media/img/whatevs/{{ item.slug }}' class="img-fluid" alt="">
```

you should have that:

```
<img src='/media/img/whatevs/{{ item.slug }}' class="img-fluid" alt="">
```

It would be a good idea to have the model return full path, it's not a good practice to put the paths in the template.